# How to get the stock quantity of the item and show it on a list.phtml page in Magento 2.2.3?

Tags: magento2, stock, quantity, magento2.2.3

I have been trying to display the stock quantity of each item on the "list.phtml" page but not getting anywhere.

Please see the attached photos as an example; this is what I have been trying to achieve. If could someone gives me the step by step guide would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: This solution seems not to be working when using Magento's MSI. Is that correct?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151957)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151957)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show qty of the product,
You can used this code.

```
$product_Id = 'YOUR_PRODUCT_ID';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$stockInfo = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($product_Id);
$stockqty = (int)$stockInfo->getQty();
echo $stockqty;
```